# Jenkins Error SonarQube Scanner execution

Tags: c#, jenkins, sonarqube

After reviewing lots of posts and blogs I still can´t figure this out.

This my current stack
Sonar: 6.3.0.19869
  Sonar Code Analyzer for C#: 5.10.1 (build 1411)
Jenkins: 2.46.1
Jenkins sonarqube scanner: 2.6.1

TFS branches:
- Dev
- Main

Sonarqube projects (deactivated rules S104, S105)
- Dev 
- Main

When  I run DEV Branch Jenkins Job, the upload to sonar DEV project is successful
When I run DEV Branch Jenkins Job, the upload to sonar Main project is successful
When I run Main Branch Jenkins Job, the upload to sonar Main project FAILS

DEV - DEV = OK

DEV - MAIN = OK

MAIN - MAIN = ERROR

Both file sets generated by sonarQube scanner are about 100Mb (Dev 111MB / Main 106MB)

```
 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Start pointer [line=4541, lineOffset=49] should be before end pointer [line=4541, lineOffset=49]
    at org.sonar.api.internal.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:145)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newRangeValidPointers(DefaultInputFile.java:265)
    at org.sonar.api.batch.fs.internal.DefaultInputFile.newRange(DefaultInputFile.java:203)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.SensorContextUtils.toTextRange(SensorContextUtils.java:41)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.SymbolRefsImporter.consumeFor(SymbolRefsImporter.java:47)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.SymbolRefsImporter.consumeFor(SymbolRefsImporter.java:33)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.ProtobufImporter.consume(ProtobufImporter.java:50)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.protobuf.RawProtobufImporter.accept(RawProtobufImporter.java:44)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.AbstractSensor.parseProtobuf(AbstractSensor.java:90)
    at org.sonarsource.dotnet.shared.plugins.AbstractSensor.importResults(AbstractSensor.java:83)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.executeInternal(CSharpSensor.java:119)
    at org.sonar.plugins.csharp.CSharpSensor.execute(CSharpSensor.java:79)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:74)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:175)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:262)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:257)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:247)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:143)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:128)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:118)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:117)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:63)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:123)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:77)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
```

What I can think of is that is something wrong with the MAIN code base, but can't figure it out

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

We recently received a bug report with the same error: [Tuple literals make the analysis fail](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-csharp/issues/391), I suppose it could be caused by other C# 7 constructs as well. Unfortunately we don't have a fix or workaround yet (except not using some C# 7 features for the time being).

I cannot promise a fix for the next version of SonarC# because we did not investigated the problem yet, but we will do our best to resolve the problem as soon as possible.